# Reload a PHP file every x seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to load a specific PHP file every 20 seconds. I need to loop the load code my code so far is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
$("#myvideos").load("http://www.mydomainz.com/myfile.php");
setTimeout(function () {
$("#myvideos").load("http://www.mydomainz.com/myfile.php");
}, 20000);
});
</script>
<div id="myvideos" style="width:300px; height:250px;"></div>
```

any ideas please?

Comment: You could use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: also when it load my file again it doens't show up the contnent of php file.. the first time that loads it, it display ok, the second it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `.load()` method in a function, taking advantage of it's callback parameter, which will be called *once the request is complete.* Only then do you want to use `setTimeout` to call your function and start the process again.

You'll need to call the function initially, when the DOM is ready.

```
function getMyVideos(){
    $("#myvideos").load("http://www.mydomainz.com/myfile.php", function(){
        setTimeout(getMyVideos, 20000);
    });
}
$(document).ready(getMyVideos);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tyacu9mz/)

Comment: this is a far superior approach than `setInterval` mentioned in comments to account for delays in requests.

Comment: @George the first load is ok, but the seconds it doesn't show anything. maybe i need to unload first from the div myvideos and load it again?